# How test coroutine correct?

Tags: android, junit4, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

Task is to clear the cache of images in the application.
Decided to do it with the help of coroutines that the application does not hang.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    AppResources.appContext?.let { Glide.get(it).clearMemory() }
}
```

But don't really understand how to write this test.